# What is the best activation function to use for time series prediction

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, sequential, activation-function

I am using the Sequential model from Keras, with the DENSE layer type. I wrote a function that recursively calculates predictions, but the predictions are way off. I am wondering what is the best activation function to use for my data. Currently I am using hard_sigmoid function. The output data values range from 5 to 25. The input data has the shape (6,1) and the output data is a single value. When I plot the predictions they never decrease. Thank you for the help!!

```
# create and fit Multilayer Perceptron model
model = Sequential();
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=look_back, activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=200, batch_size=2, verbose=0)

#function to predict using predicted values
numOfPredictions = 96;

for i in range(numOfPredictions):
    temp = [[origAndPredictions[i,0],origAndPredictions[i,1],origAndPredictions[i,2],origAndPredictions[i,3],origAndPredictions[i,4],origAndPredictions[i,5]]]
    temp = numpy.array(temp)
    temp1 = model.predict(temp)   
    predictions = numpy.append(predictions, temp1, axis=0)
    temp2 = []
    temp2 = [[origAndPredictions[i,1],origAndPredictions[i,2],origAndPredictions[i,3],origAndPredictions[i,4],origAndPredictions[i,5],predictions[i,0]]]
    temp2 = numpy.array(temp2)
    origAndPredictions = numpy.vstack((origAndPredictions, temp2))
```

[image]

update:
I used this code to implement the swish.

```
from keras.backend import sigmoid
def swish1(x, beta = 1):
    return (x * sigmoid(beta * x))
def swish2(x, beta = 1):
    return (x * sigmoid(beta * x))
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})

model.add(Activation(custom_activation,name = "swish1"))
```

[image: New plot of predictions using swish.]

update:
Using this code:

```
from keras.backend import sigmoid
from keras import backend as K
def swish1(x):
        return (K.sigmoid(x) * x)
def swish2(x):
        return (K.sigmoid(x) * x)
```

[image]

Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: What makes you think there is a best activation function given some data? There isn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there is no best activation function as such, I find [`Swish`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05941) to work particularly well for Time-Series problems. AFAIK keras doesn't provide `Swish` builtin, you can use:

```
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Activation

def custom_activation(x, beta = 1):
        return (K.sigmoid(beta * x) * x)

get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})
```

Then use it in model:

```
model.add(Activation(custom_activation,name = "Swish"))
```

Comment: Can't find the paper at the moment, at least for my usage Swish has consistently beaten every other Activation function for TimeSeries analysis. I think it ows to the fact it has properties of ReLU as well as continuous derivative at zero. So it tackles the 'Dying ReLU problem' better than `PReLU`, `LReLU` and others.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the help!! I ran the above code with the added line                                                 "from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects".                                                             I am getting the error                                  "NameError: name 'Activation' is not defined"

Comment: Use `from keras.layers import Activation`

Comment: the Swish function can be accessed through Keras `tf.keras.activations.swish`

Answer (score 1):

Your output data ranges from `5` to `25` and your output ReLU activation will give you values from `0` to `inf`. So what you try is to "parameterize" your outputs or normalize your labels. This means, using sigmoid as activation (outputs in `(0,1)`) and transform your labels by subtracting 5 and dividing by 20, so they will be in (almost) the same interval as your outputs, `[0,1]`. Or you can use sigmoid and multiply your outputs by 20 and add 5 before calculating the loss.

Would be interesting to see the results.